# User location update with MKPinAnnotationView and MKAnnotationView

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

Any idea why the following:

```
    let reuseId = "pin"
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
    pinView!.annotation = annotation
    pinView!.canShowCallout = false
    pinView!.draggable = true
```

Allows for a draggable annotation that will snap back to the user location while the following:

```
    let reuseId = "pin"
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
    pinView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
    pinView!.annotation = annotation
    pinView!.canShowCallout = false
    pinView!.draggable = true
```

Does not snap back to the user location.

This is being implemented within the viewForAnnotation function that allows you to change the current location pin.

I'm trying to edit the pin for a user location and I want it to be draggable but I want it to snap back to the user location when one is done dragging. It only does it within the MKPinAnnotationView but I need it to work for the MKAnnotatioView. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is just how the subclass is implemented unfortunately.

I think the work around is to use something like:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
        annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView 
        didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState 
        fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState 
{
    if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding)
    {
        //reset CLLocationCoordinate2D of MKAnnotation to the old coordinate (i.e. where the annotation view was before dragging)
    }
}
```

Note that I think to refresh the annotation, you might have to remove the annotation and add it back.  The pins are a lot easier to manage, but I know that they are not as easy to customize.

Comment: Ahh this makes the most sense! Thank you so so much!

Comment: Of course!  Let me know if you need any additional help. Also could you accept the answer :) :)